# OS handling of memory acces violation vs. handling of memory write violation

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, access-violation

Is it possible, and under what conditions, will the Linux kernel end execution of a program due to a memory write violation, but not due to a memory access violation over the same memory location.

eg

```
//x is a pointer to a vector of structs
if( (*x)[i].member )
     break;                   //doesn't crash

if( (*x)[i].member )
    (*x)[i].member = 1;      //crashes, even though member is not used 
                             //elsewhere in the program
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens if the page where your element is stored is write-protected.
Reads are allowed, but writes not (and the process gets killed if it tries to).

This happens with C and C++ if you try to modify a string that was stored in a read-only section.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char *foo = "hello";
  printf("%s\n", foo); // ok
  foo[0] = 'H';        // usually a crash
}
```

Comment: So If I'm trying to access an array element that hasn't been allocated, it could randomly happen that that memory (which could be allocated to a different program) is write protected?

Comment: You can't access memory owned by another process from user-space (unless you're explicitly using shared memory). Access through a pointer you didn't initialize can do just about anything, including randomly hitting a write-protected (or exec-only) page.

Comment: would unused vector capacity be write protected?

Comment: No, that's not likely at all. (Remember memory protection is per page, you can't get finer than that.)

Comment: Yes, writing to read-only memory would do that. Optimizations combined with undefined behavior could also make you _think_ you're able to read from but not write to that location, make sure that's actually what is happening.

Comment: Ok, so the only way it would be read-only memory is if the pointer had a bad address (eg. is uninitialized), correct? I'll have to make sure I am actually able to read the values.

Comment: I mean in regard to my example specifically. Your code deals with a string, but can that happen with a vector?

Comment: An uninitialized `x` could point anywhere, including a RO page. Whether there's an actual vector there is mostly irrelevant to the read part (which is probably inlined enough to be a plain memory reference).

Comment: I don't see `member` is a pointer in original-question, but a simple variable. So, read and write are on non-pointer, and therefore both read and write should crash.

Comment: @Ajay: `x` is a pointer. `(*x)[1].whatever` will try to read some memory at some offset after `x`.

Comment: @Mat Ok, but then that would be a case of the pointer having a bad address, and I was asking if that was the only way (using a vector) that the memory addressed would be read only.

Comment: For `int* p = NULL;` Both `if(p)` and `p = some_ptr;` will NOT crash. But `if(*p)` and `*p = some_value` BOTH will crash. Just think of `p` as `(*x)[i].member`

Comment: @Ajay: so? That's not what Matt is asking about.

Comment: @Matt, That's exactly the OP is asking. Read the question again, and don't go by code.

Comment: @Ajay: OP is asking about a failure on write, when no failure on read happens. You null pointer example has no failure on read or write, and failure on dereference. That's a plain null pointer handling thing. What the OP has isn't.

Comment: @Matt: unless you're playing with memory protection yourself, I don't think there is any way to get an `std::vector` to allocate its storage in a read-only section (or to get a "static" vector of some form with RO storage). So in your specific example I don't see how that error pattern could happen unless `x` is bad.

Comment: @Mat Cool, I see what you're saying. I also verified with cout that I can indeed read the locations. I'm pretty certain that its not a bad pointer, so Im kind of stumped. In chat I posted an error message that it sometimes throws instead of a segfault, any chance you could take a look at it?

Comment: "I'm pretty certain its not a bad pointer": evidence points to a bad pointer or other such corruption. What chat?

Answer (score 1):

If your array is in a read-only memory (e.g. defined as `const` or you alter its underlying memory type to read-only), then you may get a crash when attempting to change the array.

Comment: If you try to write to memory declared as "const" you would get a compile-time error and not a crash.  Whether storage is declared as "const" has little to do with whether it is physically writable or not.  You can have read-only memory that isn't "const" or writable memory that is.

Comment: @mawicks I said `may`. Also note the use of a pointer. The pointer type could hide `const` from the compiler.